# Vue.js - Remove specific component dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to dynamically create/remove a Vue component. I have figured out how to dynamically add the component, but I am having some troubles with allowing the users to remove the specific component.

Consider below two Vue files:

`TableControls.vue`

```
<a v-on:click="addColumn">Add Column</a>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            addColumn: function () {
                Event.$emit('column-was-added')
            }
        }
    };

</script>
```

`DocumentViewer.vue`:

```
<div v-for="count in columns">
   <VueDragResize :id="count">
      <a @click="removeColumn(count)">Remove Column</a>
   </VueDragResize>
</div>

<script>
import VueDragResize from 'vue-drag-resize';

    export default {
        components: {
            VueDragResize
        },
        data() {
            return {
                columns: [1],
            }

        },
        created() {
            Event.$on("column-was-added", () => this.addColumn())
        },

        methods: {
            addColumn: function () {
                this.columns.push(this.columns.length + 1)
            },
            removeColumn: function (id) {
                this.columns.splice(id, 1)
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

As you can see, whenever a user clicks on `<a v-on:click="addColumn">Add Column</a>`, it will submit an event, and the `DocumentViewer.vue` file will pick up it, firing the `addColumn` method. This will ultimately create a new `<VueDragResize></VueDragResize>` component.

This works great.

The problem is when I want to remove the component again. My `removeColumn` method simply removes an id from the `columns` array:

```
removeColumn: function (id) {
    this.columns.splice(id, 1)
}
```

This results in that a column is in fact removed. However, consider below example. When user clicks on the remove icon for the first column, it will remove the 2nd column instead. (And when there is only one column present, it cannot be removed).

[image: Vue Example]

I believe this is due to the fact that I `splice()` the array, but I cannot see how else I can remove the component dynamically?

Comment: there are missing parts in your sample. Where is the part that generates the columns ?

Comment: @y_nk sorry, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see, Array on Vue does not re render when you modify them.

You need to use the

```
Vue.set(items, indexOfItem, newValue)
```

if you want to modify

and use

```
Vue.delete(target, indexOfObjectToDelete);
```

If you want to delete an item from an array

You may read the additional info here
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete

If you want to delete an item from array. Using this will cause the component to rerender.

In this case it will be intuitive to do this

```
removeColumn: function (id) {
   Vue.delete(this.columns, id)
}
```

Note that id should be the index. Vue.delete ensures the re-render of the component.

EDIT, you must use the index, instead of the count here.

```
<div v-for="(count, index) in columns">
   <VueDragResize :id="index">
      <a @click="removeColumn(index)">Remove Column</a>
   </VueDragResize>
</div>
```

Comment: The array does rerender - it successfully modifies the array when I `addColumn` or `removeColumn`, however since I am only adding/removing ids from my array, the `<div v-for="count in columns"></div>` only increments/decrements, thus not removing the actual Vue component that was triggered.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is by using Vue.delete, it will ensure that the component will re render so, if you delete the item with index of 2, that item will be deleted and the result rendered will not include that item.

Comment: Using `Vue.delete(this.columns,id)` still removes the last added component (and only by clicking the remove button on the first component).

Comment: Instead of count, you should use the index , It seems the count starts at 1 thats why it deletes the lastly added item

Comment: but how do I access the index instead of the `count`?

Comment: I updated my answer :), index is little helper from vue, where count is the original item from the columns array

Comment: Glad to help you !

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reshaping your data, each element should be an object with an id and whatever other properties you want. Not simply an id then you would need something like this:

```
removeColumn(id) {
                const elToRemove = this.columns.findIndex(el => el.id === id)
                let newArr = [elToRemove, ...this.columns]
                this.columns = newArr
            }
```

Also make another `computed` property for `columns` like this to make sure they change dynamically (when you add/remove):

```
computed: {
      dynColumns(){ return this.columns}
    }
```

Comment: Where is `dynColumns()` used?

Comment: in your `v-for`

Comment: do you mind showing a brief example? I am a bit unsure on how to use it? Should it be like: `<div v-for="count in dynColumns">`?

Comment: Yes I meant to try what you just wrote, I am somewhat limited since you did not share all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, and I found the solution of this problem. It is need to set [#key](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html#key) with v-for. This is Built-in Special Attributes.

By default, if you do not set "#key", array index is set to#key. So if array length is 3, #key is 0,1,2. Vue identify eash v-for elements by key. If you remove second value of array, then array index is 0 and 1, because array length is 2. Then Vue understand that #key==2 element removed, So Vue remove 3rd component. So if you remove second value of array, if no #key, third component will be removed.
To avoid this, need to set #key to identify component like this:

```
let arr = [
  { id: 'a', ...},
  { id: 'b', ...},
  { id: 'c', ...}
];

<div v-for="obj in arr" :key="obj.id">
  <someYourComponent>
    ...
  </someYourComponent>
</div>
```